# It is possible to requestWindowFeature in Android manifest?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I would like to specify that I want `FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS` for my `Activity`.

It can be done in android manifest or I must do it in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, I believe that you have to do it in code like this:

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
```

I am not to familiar about doing this in the Manifest because you are requesting this from Window. However, you can do other things in your manifest like setting the style and theme of your activity.

Also, remember to add that line before `setContentView(R.layout.main);` because the features being requested must be completed before the activities views are set.